# How to render H.264 transport streams into an HTML5 player

Tags: html, h.264, jwplayer, flowplayer, transport-stream

I wanna code a simple HTML5 page for streaming video contents.

My video source is a H.264 TS over HTTP generated by VLC by a command line very similar to this:

```
vlc -vvv source --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:9955/live}'
```

I've tried with JWPlayer and Flowplayer but none of them supports H.264 streams incapsulated in TS.

I cannot change the original vlc command line since it's running on an external server, but I can run another instance of vlc on my server to remux it in another container if needed (No reencoding since the source is already LQ).
Any hint?

Comment: For the stream? Nope, I cannot reshare it. But I can give you a Mediainfo analysis if you need it http://pastebin.com/V6k9jzk0 .

Comment: I want a link to where the player is embedded.

Comment: Locally on my pc ATM.

Using JWPlayer the source of the php page is something like this: http://pastebin.com/Ym1WCjU2

Ofc you have to change yourcustomkey to your own JWPlayer key and domain:9955 to the URL where the VLC Stream is. I cannot share my JWPlayer custom key since it's the paid version.

Comment: That should be ok, but I would need to see something to be able to debug properly.

Comment: I have been able to use VLC to generate a HLS stream using my webcam locally. This is the command if it helps - "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"  -vvv -I rc --ttl 12 dshow:// vdev="VGA USB Camera" adev="USB Camera" size="320x240" --sout=#transcode{width=320,height=240,fps=15,vcodec=h264,venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=10,ref=1},acodec=mp3,ab=96}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=1,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,index=C:\xampp\htdocs\stream\mystream.m3u8,index-url=http://localhost/stream/mystream-########.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=C:\xampp\htdocs\stream\mystream-########.ts}

Comment: Ok, i've put up a simple page with a free JWPlayer key. You can access it from http://cusy.homedns.org/videoplayer/ . It should stream the Big Buck Bunny video from cusy.homedns.org:8080/live.ts

The vlc stream is created using the same command line posted in the first initial question.

My connection is very poor (only 386kbps upload speed) so video playback will be slow and with artifacts.

Comment: This will not work because the player is free. You need premium for HLS on the desktop.

Comment: That's not a HLS stream, since I can open it with VLC pre-2.0 that doesn't have HLS support according to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming#Clients

Comment: Set the type variable to hls in the player set up.